# stats.sh error in BBmap package

Tags: fasta, sequence-analysis, linux

I am trying to calculate the N50 value from the assembled FASTA file. I used stats.sh from the BBmap package. I executed the following command

```
./stats.sh  in=/Home/Downloads/BBMap_39.01/bbmap/resources/contig.fasta
```

I got the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Input file does not appear to be valid: /Home/Downloads/BBMap_39.01/bbmap/resources/contig.fasta
    at jgi.AssemblyStats2.process(AssemblyStats2.java:248)
    at jgi.AssemblyStats2.main(AssemblyStats2.java:40)
```

How to resolve this error?

The sequences are shown below. My file also contains some lengthy sequences.

```
>NODE_1_length_3013_cov_4.540906
TGGGGGATCATGTAACTCGCCTTGATCGTTGGGAACCGGAGCTGAATGAAGCCATACCAA
ACGACGAGCGTGACACCACGATGCCTGTAGCAATGGCAACAACGTTGCGCAAACTATTAA
CTGGCGAACTACTTACTCTAGCTTCCCGGCAACAATTAATAGACTGGATGGAGGCGGATA
AAGTTGCAGGACCACTTCTGCGCTCGGCCCTTCCGGCTGGCTGGTTTATTGCTGATAAAT
CTGGAGCCGGTGAGCGTGGGTCTCGCGGTATCATTGCAGCACTGGGGCCAGATGGTAAGC
CCTCCCGTATCGTAGTTATCTACACGACGGGGAGTCAGGCAACTATGGATGAACGAAATA
GACAGATCGCTGAGATAGGTGCCTCACTGATTAAGCATTGGTAACTGTCAGACCAAGTTT
>NODE_2_length_2292_cov_16.637908
CAAAGGAATAATAATTGACTGATGATTGGTTCATTAATTACTTCATTAGTTAATAGATTG
CAGTCTTTATAAATAAGTTTATAGTTGTATTCCACAGAATTTCTGATCCTGTCTCTGCCC
TACCCAATGTTTTATCATTAAACTTCATTTACATAAGATAGTATGTTCAACAAATATAAA
GATTTGCTGGAATGGAAGGCACAGTAAGATATTTCACAGGATAAAATTAAAGTAGATGTC
AACAGAGTAAATCAAAGTGAAATTTAATAGAGTTAAACAGTAAGTGTTTTAAATACCAGG
ATTAAATTCCATGAAGCTGCAGCTTTTAAAAAAAGGCACAAAGTGGAATAAGAAAAAATG
ACTTTCAGAAAGTTAATGTAAAGAAAGCTCACGGTTTTCATTGGCTGCCTGCTCAGTTTG
```

Comment: Also, why you run this on a file provided by bbmap rather than your own?

Comment: @ATpoint Thank you for your comment. contig.fasta is my file. I just copied to the resources directory.

Comment: Hmmm. Is this a permissions error? Can you type `ls -l /Home/Downloads/BBMap_39.01/bbmap/resources/contig.fasta` and report the output?

Comment: @M_. Thanks for your comment. ls -l shows the list of files. The first two lines are shown. -rwxrwxrwx  1 user user  2674 Jun 12  2020 addadapters.sh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 user user  2674 Jun 12  2020 addadapters.sh

Comment: I agree with @atpoint as best guess. `ls /home/Downloads/BBMap_39.01/bbmap/resources/contig.fasta` , i.e. lower case `h`.  It could be other things. Can you try their test data?

Answer (score 1):

```bash
./stats.sh in=notExistingFile.fa
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Input file does not appear to be valid: notExistingFile.fa
        at jgi.AssemblyStats2.process(AssemblyStats2.java:248)
        at jgi.AssemblyStats2.main(AssemblyStats2.java:40)
```

The error comes when the file does not exist. My best guess is that it is a typo on your side. Is the path really `/Home` with capital "H"? Most OS like Linux and macOS use lowercase. Anyway, make sure the file exists.